# How to hide angular version from wappalyzer?

Tags: angular

for some security reasons I need to **hide javascript frameworks version especially angular from wappalyzer** but I have no idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove ng-version attribute from app component to solve the problem.

```
@Component({
    selector: '[data-app]',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._elementRef.nativeElement.removeAttribute("ng-version");
    }
}
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: Relevant thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16283